# ktor server - when to move to another coroutine context

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor

This may be a question about coroutines in general, but in my ktor server (netty engine, default configuration) application I perform  serveral asyncronous calls to a database and api endpoint and want to make sure I am using coroutines efficiently. My question are as follows:

1. Is there a tool or method to work out if my code is using coroutines effectively, or do I just need to use curl to spam my endpoint and measure the performance of moving processes to another context e.g. `compute`?
2. I don't want to start moving tasks/jobs to another context 'just in case' but should I treat the default coroutine context in my `Route.route()` similar to the Android main thread and perform the minimum amount of work on it?

Here is an rough example of the code that I'm using:

```
fun Route.route() {
    get("/") {
        call.respondText(getRemoteText())
    }
}

suspend fun getRemoteText() : String? {
   return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        val document = 3rdPartyLibrary.get()
            if (success) {
                cont.resume(data)
            } else {
                cont.resume(null)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `getRemoteText` doesn't look correct because it seems to use a blocking call `3cdPartLibrary.get()`. This is already proof that you aren't using coroutines effectively.

Comment: Thats why I wrapped the blocking operation in a ```suspendCoroutine```...

Comment: That doesn't do anything, you can't un-block a call using Kotlin coroutines. You should use an async API that you can adapt to a suspendable function. If you keep the blocking call, coroutines can only give you some side benefits, like more convenience in submitting a blocking call to a thread pool. However, that approach does not involve `suspendCoroutine` but `withContext(IO)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use something like [Apache Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), but writing a script and spamming your server with curl seems also a good option to me
2. Coroutines are pretty efficient when it comes to `context`/`thread` switching, and with `Dispatchers.Default` and `Dispatchers.IO` you'll get a thread-pool. There are a couple of documentations around this, but I think you can definitely leverage these Dispatchers for heavy operations

Answer (score 0):

1. There are few tools for testing endpoints. Jmeter is good, there are also command line tools like wrk, wrk2 and siege.
2. Of course context switching costs. The coroutine in routing is safe to run blocking operations unless you have the option `shareWorkGroup` set. However, usually it's good to use a separate thread pool because you can control it's size (max threads number) to not get you database down.